# Proper code to filter a price range in PHP / SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

Really hoping someone can help me with this. I'm building a PHP / MySQL search form that, hopefully, will allow users to search our wine database and filter the results according to a range of prices selected via a drop down menu.

The form works fine searching for, and returning, a nice list of accurate results. But it does NOT price filter the results.

After days of searching and experimenting, I've mashed together various code snippets to get this far but, overall, PHP is still very much a mystery to me.

It's the correct coding and syntax I struggle with.

How might I code the PHP posted here to properly integrate the Price Range filter? I suspect my inclusion of "pricerange" in the sql query is way off base.

- MySQL Server version: 5.1.65-cll
- Price column type: decimal(10,2)

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Please check the code blocks below.

Thanks a ton!

### HTML

```
 <form  method="post" action="winesearch.php?go" id="searchform"> 
 <input  type="text" size="35" name="user-entry"/>
 <select name="pricerange" size="1" id="pricerange">
    <option value="">Price Range&nbsp;</option>
    <option value="1">$&nbsp;10 - $20</option>
    <option value="2">$&nbsp;21 - $30</option>
    <option value="3">$&nbsp;31 - $50</option>
    <option value="4">$&nbsp;51 - $75</option>
    <option value="5">$&nbsp;76 - $100</option>
    <option value="6">$101 - $200</option>
    <option value="7">$201 - Plus</option>
</select> 
<input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Wine Search"/> 
</form>
```

### PHP

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if(isset($_GET['go'])){
  if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+/", $_POST['user-entry'])){
  $cob=$_POST['user-entry'];
  $pricerange=$_POST['pricerange'];


  //connect to the database
  $db=mysql_connect  ("server", "user", "pass") or die (mysql_error());

  //-select the database to use
  $mydb=mysql_select_db("db_name");

  if($pricerange == 0) $pricerange = 1;

  switch ($pricerange) {
  case 1  :  $pricerange = " where Price BETWEEN 10.00 AND 20.00 ";  break; 
  case 2  :  $pricerange = " where Price BETWEEN 21.00 AND 30.00 ";  break;  
  case 3  :  $pricerange = " where Price BETWEEN 31.00 AND 50.00 ";  break;   
  case 4  :  $pricerange = " where Price BETWEEN 51.00 AND 75.00 ";  break;     
  case 5  :  $pricerange = " where Price BETWEEN 76.00 AND 100.00 ";  break;       
  case 6  :  $pricerange = " where Price BETWEEN 101.00 AND 200.00 ";  break;         
  case 7  :  $pricerange = " where Price > 200.00 ";  break;           
  }

  //-query the database table
  $sql="
    SELECT  ID, 
    CSPC, 
    Country,
    Producer,
    Wine,
    Year,
    Price 
    FROM winecellar WHERE 
    CSPC LIKE '%" . $cob .  "%' 
    OR 
    Country LIKE '%" . $cob ."%'
    OR 
    Producer LIKE '%" . $cob ."%'
    OR 
    Wine LIKE '%" . $cob ."%'
    OR 
    Year LIKE '%" . $cob ."%'
    OR 
    Price LIKE '%" . $pricerange ."%'
    ";

  //-run  the query against the mysql query function
  $result=mysql_query($sql);

  //-create  while loop and loop through result set
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $CSPC=$row['CSPC'];
    $Country=$row['Country'];
    $Producer=$row['Producer'];
    $Wine=$row['Wine'];
    $Year=$row['Year']; 
    $Price=$row['Price'];
    $ID=$row['ID'];

    //-display the result of the array
echo  "<ul>\n";
echo  "<li>" . $CSPC . "</li>\n";
echo  "<li>" . $Country . "</li>\n";
echo  "<li>" . $Producer . "</li>\n";
echo  "<li>" . $Wine . "</li>\n";
echo  "<li>" . $Year . "</li>\n";
echo  "<li>" . "<a href=" . $Price .  ">" . "$" . $Price . "</a></li>\n";

echo  "</ul>";
  }
  }
  else{
  echo  "<p>Please enter a search query</p>";
  }
  }
  }
?>
```

Comment: What doesn't work exactly?  Do you know exactly what SQL statement you have built? Have you printed the `$sql` that you have built before executing it?

Comment: first remove `WHERE` clause from `$pricerange`

Comment: If the size of your products is relatively small I would consider removing the price range from the search feature.  Then list all, and add a jquery table sorter on your results.  Then the user can sort based on your table headers.  Also, currently you display the results in an unordered list, might reconsider that as well.

Comment: Thanks gSaenz, that's a great idea. IF I can't get this drop down to work, that's definitely the approach I need, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if(isset($_GET['go'])){
   // improved the filter to support space and -
   // Also closed critical security breache (SQL-injection)
  if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 -]+$/", $_POST['user-entry'])){
  $cob=$_POST['user-entry'];
  $pricerange=$_POST['pricerange'];


  //connect to the database
  $db=mysql_connect  ("server", "user", "pass") or die (mysql_error());

  //-select the database to use
  $mydb=mysql_select_db("db_name");

  switch ($pricerange) {
  case 2  :  $pricerange = " AND Price BETWEEN 21.00 AND 30.00 ";  break;  
  case 3  :  $pricerange = " AND Price BETWEEN 31.00 AND 50.00 ";  break;   
  case 4  :  $pricerange = " AND Price BETWEEN 51.00 AND 75.00 ";  break;     
  case 5  :  $pricerange = " AND Price BETWEEN 76.00 AND 100.00 ";  break;       
  case 6  :  $pricerange = " AND Price BETWEEN 101.00 AND 200.00 ";  break;         
  case 7  :  $pricerange = " AND Price > 200.00 ";  break;
  default :  $pricerange = " AND Price BETWEEN 10.00 AND 20.00 "; // covers all other cases
  }

  //-query the database table
  $sql="
    SELECT  ID, 
    CSPC, 
    Country,
    Producer,
    Wine,
    Year,
    Price 
    FROM winecellar WHERE 
    (CSPC LIKE '%" . $cob .  "%' 
    OR 
    Country LIKE '%" . $cob ."%'
    OR 
    Producer LIKE '%" . $cob ."%'
    OR 
    Wine LIKE '%" . $cob ."%'
    OR 
    Year LIKE '%" . $cob ."%')
    " . $pricerange;

  //-run  the query against the mysql query function
  $result=mysql_query($sql);

  //-create  while loop and loop through result set
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $CSPC=$row['CSPC'];
    $Country=$row['Country'];
    $Producer=$row['Producer'];
    $Wine=$row['Wine'];
    $Year=$row['Year']; 
    $Price=$row['Price'];
    $ID=$row['ID'];

    //-display the result of the array
echo  "<ul>\n";
echo  "<li>" . $CSPC . "</li>\n";
echo  "<li>" . $Country . "</li>\n";
echo  "<li>" . $Producer . "</li>\n";
echo  "<li>" . $Wine . "</li>\n";
echo  "<li>" . $Year . "</li>\n";
echo  "<li>" . "<a href=" . $Price .  ">" . "$" . $Price . "</a></li>\n";

echo  "</ul>";
  }
  }
  else{
  echo  "<p>Please enter a search query</p>";
  }
  }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Also there is no need of `Price LIKE`

Comment: Thanks Andy, Alexander and GBD for the super-fast feedback!  Sorry, I'm not well versed in this. I just made the changes Alexander suggested, but now the form stays entirely blank and no error messages are returned. Could it be something wrong in the while loop or echo display? I'm just guessing ..

Comment: Thanks Alexander, very much appreciated, I'll give your new changes a try right now ...

Comment: Can't tell you how much I appreciate the help guys, awesome! Alexander, I've made the changes you suggested, and now receive the follow error message: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected  '}'  on line 152.  Which is the closing curly brace here:      default: $pricerange = '' }

Comment: OK. I must stop trying to quick-fix your problem. I'll return a couple of hours later when I'll have a time to provide you with full solution

Comment: Thanks so much Alexander, I've adjusted the code without the `default: $pricerange = ''` and now it returns ALL the wines in the right price range PLUS all the wines whose name (Merlot) I entered into the search box. I would like to filter the Merlot (for example) so that, just those within the selected price range are returned, and nothing else. But I'm on the right path thanks to you guys, look forward to hearing from you again :)

Comment: I've updated my initial answer with improved code. You may use it or not, but line 7 must be changed. These was very dangerous SQL injection vulnerability in this line. I fixed this. I strongly recommend using mysql_real_escape_string() on all input from web forms before using it in mysql queries

Comment: Alexander, you rock!  Thank you my friend, works PERFECTLY. Very much appreciate your efforts and considerable talent. All the best .. Chris.

Answer (score 1):

You had it right up until you put the query together. You don't need the "where" in the statements below since you already have it in the query you're building below.

```
switch ($pricerange) {
  case 1  :  $pricerange = " Price BETWEEN 10.00 AND 20.00 ";  break; 
  case 2  :  $pricerange = " Price BETWEEN 21.00 AND 30.00 ";  break;  
  case 3  :  $pricerange = " Price BETWEEN 31.00 AND 50.00 ";  break;   
  case 4  :  $pricerange = " Price BETWEEN 51.00 AND 75.00 ";  break;     
  case 5  :  $pricerange = " Price BETWEEN 76.00 AND 100.00 ";  break;       
  case 6  :  $pricerange = " Price BETWEEN 101.00 AND 200.00 ";  break;         
  case 6  :  $pricerange = " Price > 200.00 ";  break;           
}

OR 
Price LIKE '%" . $pricerange ."%'
```

should be

```
OR ". $pricerange ."
```

because you're already building the between statements.

Comment: MagicMarkker:  Thanks very much for your input.  I think we are  getting close. with your suggestions.

Comment: I've adjusted the code as you indicated above. Now the form returns ALL the wines in the right price range PLUS all the wines whose name (Merlot) I entered into the search box. I would like to filter the Merlot (for example) so that, just those within the selected price range are returned, and nothing else.  Any thoughts on this?  Again, thank you!

Comment: change the `OR ". $pricerange ."` to 'AND ". $pricerange ."` and if there is a pricerange set, you would remove all of the OR statements that you don't want to display anymore. So you'll have to build the query dynamically with a few if statements.

Comment: Thank you, I'll search around for a suitable if statement block and see what turns up, at least I'm on the right path, everyone's been great! Thanks again ..

Answer (score 1):

I would echo out your sql query before it is run so you can see what it looks like.  But it appears that the SQL part is wrong for the pricerange section.  Right now it would look like this:

```
OR Price LIKE '% where price BETWEEN 10.00 AND 20.00 %'
```

I would think you would want it to look like:

```
OR PRICE BETWEEN 10.00 AND 20.00
```

Do you want that to be an 'or' or an 'and'?